# iOS Swift - Trying to convert a String to Date. Which is the correct dateFormat for this date? Sun, 01 Oct 2023 00:00:00 GMT

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to convert a String into a Date object. The String contains a date in this format "Sun, 01 Oct 2023 00:00:00 GMT".

What i did is this:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")


// dateObject -> Date / StringDate -> String       
item.dateObject = item.stringDate?.toDate(formatter: formatter)

// toDate method
extension String {

func toDate(formatter: DateFormatter) -> Date? {
    if let dateFromString = formatter.date(from: self) {
            return dateFromString
    } else {
        return nil
    }
 }
}
```

But unfortunately item.dateObject is nil. I've put a breakpoint in the toDate method and it stops to "return nil". Is the dateFormat correct for that type of date?

Thanks.

Comment: I haven’t tried your code but one thing I spot is two digits for day so try dd instead.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson tried with "E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z" but still fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format `"E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"` is valid for `Sun, 01 Oct 2023 00:00:00 GMT`

Some notes:

1. A two digit day is actually `dd`.
2. Specifying the time zone of the formatter is redundant since it's part of the time string.
3. According to the [Unicode specifications](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) the pattern for a three letter zone identifier is lowercase `z`.
4. It's highly recommended to specify a fixed `Locale` when applying a custom date format.

---

```
let timeString = "Sun, 01 Oct 2023 00:00:00 GMT"

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"
if let date = formatter.date(from: timeString) {
    print(date)
}
```